# Rotational Symmetry with Point Lights?

Tags: modifiers, light

I am working on a scene where I have a pyramid with three lights at each corner of the base. I want to be able to animate one light and have the others move the same way, with three fold rotational symmetry around a point. Usually you would use a mirror modifier with an offset, but as you can't do that with point lights, I was wondering if there is any way to do it.

Edit: To give more of an idea, [this](https://i.stack.imgur.com/2m6Wg.jpg) is the movement I want to do. While I could do it manually, I want to see if there's a way to do it just by moving/animating one.

Comment: Currently lights and empties should be parented to a plane which can be used as an instance object. The plane can be set to instance from faces or verts and have modifiers applied to it to perform the old rotational array steps.

Answer (score 0):

as Ratt said you can do it like so:

1. first: Shift - A -> Add plane
2. scale, rotate, place it as you need it
3. add a light
4. select your plane and tap on vertices

[image]

5. Shift - select your light -> now you got 4 lights which move with your plane
6. add an array modifier...now you got 4 x count lights ;)

[image]

Answer (score 0):

If I understand correctly, you can create your light, parent it to an empty at the same location:

[image]

Link-duplicate the light + empty, put it at another corner, rotate the empty 120° on Z:

[image]

Give this second light a *Copy Rotation* constraint (or *Copy Transfoms* if you need to copy location as well), *Local Space*, and with the first light as *Target*:

[image]

Now when you move the first light, the second will copy its rotation.